# How to set alpha for the smoothing line in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha, scatter-plot, smoothing

I am using alpha to set transparency for the smoothing line in ggplot but instead I get transparency only in the Error band that surrounds the fitted line.

My code is the following:

```
z1 <- rnorm(10)

z2 <- z1 ^ 2

error <- rnorm(10, 0.25)

y <- 1 + 0.5 * z1 + error

data1 <- data.table(y, z1, z2)

ggplot(data1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = z1, y = y), color = "blue", size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = z2, y = y), color = "red", size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(x = z1, y = y), color = "blue", size = 2, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(x = z2, y = y), color = "red", size = 2, alpha = 0.1)
```

The output is this:
[image]

How can I set explicitly the transparency of the regression line as well?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: @Jaap, I don't know the protocol on linking to external sites, but there is a really good answer to this question on google groups (but not on SO). The link is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/mE__po966-k. It might be worthwhile to include it as an answer for future SO readers, but again I don't know if that is frowned upon in SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `geom_line` for more fine-grained control of the regression line.

```r
ggplot(data1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = z1, y = y), color = "blue", size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = z2, y = y), color = "red", size = 3) +
  geom_line(stat = "smooth", method = lm, aes(x = z1, y = y), color = "blue", size = 2, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_line(stat = "smooth", method = lm, aes(x = z2, y = y), color = "red", size = 2, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(x = z1, y = y), color = NA, size = 2, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(x = z2, y = y), color = NA, size = 2, alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: you can also use `geom_ribbon(stat = "smooth")` for the se ribbons